# How to create style in style.xml for Roboto assets

Tags: android, android-layout, styles

I have included the Roboto fonts in my project as assets. So now to define a TextView I can do

```
<me.android.fonts.widget.RobotoTextView
        android:id="@+id/day"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:typeface="roboto_bold"
        android:textColor="@color/green_text"
        android:textSize="@dimen/day_size"
        tools:text="Tues"/>
```

Now image I have a number of TextView that need to be style. Typically, I can simply define a style and reuse it. But I am not able to do that in the present situation because of `app:typeface`. How do Include that in my 'style.xml' file? I already tried

```
<resources xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
...
<style...>
...
</style>
</resources>
```

but that does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**style.xml**

```
<resources>
<style name="WidgetStyle.TextMedium">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="typeface">roboto_bold</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

(Assuming you are using android studio)

Hope it helps you..